# Swing: FileDialog stuck in long process

Tags: java, swing, awt, filedialog

We use FileDialog for open/save menus. When we save the file, first we populate the modal window using FileDialog. After user inputs the file name, the saving operation takes a long time ( up to 45 seconds) as there is a time consuming export process involved. So the problem is, during the export process, the FileDialog window is closed but there is a gray area in the FileDialog's location. Until the saving process is completed, the gray area will be cleared. Code is:

```
 File file = null;
 File fd = new FileDialog(mainFrame, "Save", FileDialog.SAVE);

 fd.setDirectory("./");
 fd.setLocation(50, 50);
 fd.setVisible(true);

 if (fd.getFile() != null) {
   file = new File(fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile());
 }

 // This is a time consuming process
 ExportFromDB edb = new ExportFromDB(); 
 // Program continues
```

Is there any way to clear the FileDialog window completely? thanks

Comment: your "export" process shall be in another thread.

Comment: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details. 2) The `FileDialog` is AWT, not Swing.  The Swing equivalent is [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gray box you are seeing is because the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) is blocked and is unable to update the GUI.

You should look into using [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to perform the long running task on a background thread.

Another option available under Java 7 is [SecondaryLoop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SecondaryLoop.html).

Take a look at [Hidden Java 7 Features – SecondaryLoop](https://web.archive.org/web/20150418054037/http://sellmic.com/blog/2012/02/29/hidden-java-7-features-secondaryloop) for a detailed explanation & example.

Answer (score 1):

Your UI is going to be "Stuck" until your export finishes, the best thing to do would be to do the work in a separate thread.